# Resource.designer.cs is broken in Visual Studio Xamarin when using Android Class Library

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have Xamarin Android app `MyApp.Droid`. It references Android Class Library `MyAndroidLib.Droid`. This library contains `Resources/Values/Strings.xml` file with just template content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="Hello">Hello World, Click Me!</string>
    <string name="ApplicationName">$projectname$</string>
</resources
```

Whenever I save or try to build project I get errors in `MyApp.Droid` in `Resource.designer.cs` at lines:

```
global::MyAndroidLib.Droid.Resource.String.ApplicationName =       
    global::MyApp.Droid.Resource.String.ApplicationName;
global::MyAndroidLib.Droid.Resource.String.Hello = 
    global::MyApp.Droid.Resource.String.Hello;
```

The thing is that those string doesn't exist in `MyApp.Droid` but Visual Studio still wants to assign them.

Xamarin Studio on Mac doesn't have this behavior and everything works and compiles.

Is there a way to prevent these errors? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar error.

Comment: Yes... but I don't remember how... I tried many things. A lot of times deleting designer.cs files, everything in all bin and obj folders and rebuilding the solution helped in such issues. Important thing is that Clean project is not enough. You must manually remove bin and obj folders.